# MS Access 2007: Add date to Excel Export

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I currently have a 'Save Export' task that is saving a table (+1 million records) to an .xlsx file on a SharePoint folder via mapped network drive.  I want to add the date to the file Excel file name.

Currently for Export-Excel Spreadsheet:
File Name is: `U:\Reporting\Extracts\Excel_filename.xlsx`
File format: `Excel Workbook (*.xlsx)`
Under Specify export options: I don't have anything checked.

With Date:
File Name is: `U:\Reporting\Extracts\Excel_filename_mm_dd_yyyy.xlsx`
File format: `Excel Workbook (*.xlsx)`
Under Specify export options: I don't have anything checked.

I would want the final file name to be: `Excel_filename_09_18_213.xlsx`

I don't want to use VBA because creating the .xlsx file takes over 4 hours.  Export the table directly to the SharePoint folder is faster, but I need to update the file name with the current date.   Could I create a macro that adds the date to the file name before it is posted to SharePoint?  Is there a 'RunCommand' or 'RunCode' command that I could run that would generate the file name with the date?

I have tried the following for the file name, and they didn't work.  I get "Failed creating file." "The specification failed to execute. Try re-creating the specification.":

```
U:\Reporting\Extracts\Excel_filename&(Format(Date()),"yymmdd"))&.xlsx
U:\Reporting\Extracts\Excel_filename%Date:~12,2%%Date:~4,2,%%Date:7~2%.xlsx
"U:\Reporting\Extracts\Excel_filename"&(Format(Date()),"yymmdd"))&".xlsx"
U:\Reporting\Extracts\Excel_filename_(Format(Date()),"yymmdd")).xlsx
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use VBA for this task.   I wouldn't save it directly from Access onto Sharepoint folder however, I'd save it to a temporary location on the local disk and then copy it over - much quicker.  If you are talking about pulling the data from a local Access file - then it shouldn't be taking 4 hours.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport,acSpreadsheetTypeExcel7, "myAccessTable", _
            "C:\MyExcelExport_" & format(date(),"yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xls", True
```

Answer (score 0):

on the macro line set destination 
            ="C:\YourFolder\fileName" & Format(Date(),"ddmmyy") & ".xls"